# Why we get error while set the useState method in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Here I am using the `react` `usestate hook` I have make the usestate as

```
const { blogs, setBlogs } = useState([{postId:"",blogCity:"",blogTitle:"",username:"",time:""}]);
```

Now I want to store multiple blogs in this `usestate` But the `useEffect` hook return the error of setBlogs is not a function. the code of useEffect is

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetchProfileImage();
        fetchPost();
        getBlogs();
    }, [postImage,blogs,setBlogs])
```

I fetched the blogs from getBlogs function where the function is

```
const getBlogs =async()=>{
    const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/post/getPost/${username}`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'auth-token': localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json.result);
    setBlogs( json.result);
    console.log("here",blogs);
}
```

The blog data is fetched properly from the database but it can't be stored by `setBlogs`. How I can store the blog data in `blogs` usestate.
The error is

```
User.js:75 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setBlogs is not a function
    at getBlog
```

The error occurs while I use `setBlogs` usestate.

Answer (score 3):

`useState` returns an array of two elements: an object representing the current state and a setter for the state. You have to deconstruct what `useState` returns into an array with two objects instead of an object with two properties as you do now.

Wrong: `const { blogs, setBlogs } = useState([...]);`

Correct: `const [ blogs, setBlogs ] = useState([...]);`